# How to translate a simple query from influxQL to Flux

Tags: java, flux, influxql

I need to convert this query written in InfluxQL
USE MyDB; DROP SERIES FROM MyDB.autogen.MyTable WHERE MyTakKey = 'MyTagValue'

I need to convert into flux.

String influxQuery = "from(bucket:"MyDB/autogen")" + " |> range(start: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2023-06-30T00:00:00Z)" + " |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "" + measurement + "" " + " and r.MyTakKey == "" + "MyTagValue" + "")" + " |> drop(columns:" + field + ")";